# Convert Evolution filters.xml file to Thunderbird msgFilterRules.dat?

Tags: xml, thunderbird, evolution

I migrated evolution to Thunderbird yesterday. I googled for migrate filters, but Evolution stores them as an XML file and Thunderbird stores using a [Mork formatted](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mork_%28file_format%29) file such as:

```
version=`9`
logging=
name=
enabled=
type=
action=
actionValue=
condition=
name=
enabled=
type=
action=
actionValue=
condition=
...
```

#### Question

Before starting to code anything that will convert XML to Mork, I did a little R&D for avoiding re-creating the wheel, but still it would seem to me to be something that another developer would've already created.

Please ensure me I'm not reinventing the wheel here.

Comment: I'm not finding anything either.

Answer (score 0):

Thunderbird (TB) stores message filters in plain text in
the msgFilterRules.dat file, 
which is **not** in the rather opaque Mork format.

A reasonable approach to converting filters is to create 
a few filters in TB, test them for functionality,
exit TB completely, and view the msgFilterRules.dat
file (found in the TB profile directory) with a text editor.

The format should be fairly clear from inspection,
and converting most filters from XML should be 
approachable with scripting tools, with the capability 
of editing in TB available as a fall-back.  For details see:

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Filters_(Thunderbird)